# PHP fgets runs indefinitely

Tags: php

I have built myself a simple HTTP request object, very basic

```
class Request {

    protected $hostname;
    protected $port = 80;
    protected $method = 'GET';
    protected $uri = '/';
    protected $headers = array();
    protected $body;
    protected $handle;
    protected $response;

    public function __construct() {
        $cookies = null;
        foreach (\Cookie::getAll() as $k => $v) {
            $cookies .= urlencode($k) . '=' . urlencode($v) . '; ';
        }
        $this->setHeader('Cookie', substr($cookies, 0, -2));
    }

    public function setHostname($name, $ssl = false) {
        if (filter_var(gethostbyname($name), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
            $this->hostname = ($ssl ? 'ssl://' : null) . $name;
            $this->setHeader('Host', $name);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function setPort($port) {
        if ($port >= 1 && $port <= 65535) {
            $this->port = (int)$port;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function setMethod($method) {
        $methods = [
            'GET' => true,
            'POST' => true,
            'PUT' => true,
            'DELETE' => true
        ];

        if (isset($methods[$method])) {
            $this->method = strtoupper($method);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function setUri($uri) {
        $this->uri = $uri;
        return true;
    }

    public function setHeader($key, $value) {
        $this->headers[$key] = $value;
        return true;
    }

    public function removeHeader($key) {
        unset($this->headers[$key]);
        return true;
    }

    public function setBody($body) {
        $this->body = $body;
        return true;
    }

    public function send($async = false, $timeout = 30) {
        $errno = null;
        $errstr = null;

        $this->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($this->body));
        if($async){
            $this->setHeader('Connection', 'Close');
        }

        $this->response = null;
        $this->handle = fsockopen($this->hostname, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
        if (!$this->handle) {
            throw new \Exception($errstr, $errno);
        }

        $headers = null;
        foreach ($this->headers as $key => $value) {
            $headers .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
        }

        $request = "{$this->method} {$this->uri} HTTP/1.1\r\n{$headers}\r\n" . $this->body;

        fwrite($this->handle, $request);

        if ($async) {
            fclose($this->handle);
            return;
        }

        while (!feof($this->handle)) {
            echo $this->response . ' dgd<br/><br/><br/>';
            $this->response .= fgets($this->handle, 8192);
        }
        fclose($this->handle);
    }

    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

When I send an "asynchronous" there's no problems but when I try to get the response I get maximum execution time exceeded error. I added an echo into the response-reading loop to debug and it only runs once. What may the problem be?

```
$r = new \Request();
$r->setHostname('localhost');
$r->setUri('/test.php');
$r->send();

echo "<pre>" . print_r($r, true) . "</pre>";
```

test.php

```
echo 'Test complete.';
```

Response source of the initial request

```
 dgd<br/><br/><br/><br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in <b>....\Request.php</b> on line <b>98</b><br />
```

Where line 98 is

```
$this->response .= fgets($this->handle, 8192);
```

Comment: I'm all for figuring out how stuff works, but building your own HTTP library isn't as easy as you seem to think. You also need to consider what to do when receiving `302`, `301`, `200 CONTINUE` headers etc. Is there any reason you can't use cURL or guzzle?

Comment: I'm not concerned about this because the purpose of this object is to send requests to my application only and I know what the responses would be. The problem for now is that I can't read the response. @h2ooooooo regarding your question - I decided not to use other libraries exactly because of the fact that they are more complex and built to handle various situations, while I don't need all of this functionality for my purposes.

Comment: @KarelKubat I agree the name might be a little confusing, basically it means send the request and don't wait for reply, with the idea of not slowing down the client response of the initial request. As to `feof` on closed handles, there is no way the handle can be closed because if `async` is true then the function will return before getting to `feof`

Comment: is the client that is sending data which your `fgets()` is reading sending data and then closing the socket?

Comment: @RichardChambers I'm sorry but I just can't wrap my head around what you just said.

Comment: The fgets() will try to read as many characters as you specify in the length unless there is some kind of a condition such as end of file or socket close.  try reading a few characters in the loop like maybe 3 and see if it iterates multiple times.  I suspect the client that is sending data is not sending data then closing the socket.

Answer (score 2):

The `fgets()` will read data from the socket and complete the read under several conditions such as end of file, the length - 1 number of characters read, or socket close.

The first thing you could try is to change your length to a much smaller value to see if you can get multiple reads. This will tell you whether the loop is working and the `fgets()` is not seeing the proper read termination behavior from the client that is sending data through the socket which is being read by the `fgets()`.

What I suspect is that the client which is sending data is not closing the socket after sending the data.

The HTTP protocol is really designed to be stateless. The basic procedure is that the client should open a socket, send an HTTP request, get an HTTP response from the server, and then close the socket. However you can modify this procedure with the proper changes in the client and the server so as to maintain a connection sending and receiving data such as JSON or XML.

Since a TCP connection is a simple byte stream, any coordination between client and server where a connection is maintained must be implemented with some agreement by the client and the server as to the structure of the data. Using JSON or XML is pretty straightforward as those have messages have a structure where you know the beginning and the ending of a message.

For simple HTTP using the standard HTTP procedure, the end of the message is communicated by the closing of the socket by the client after it receives the HTTP response from the server. This tells the server that the communication is done.

Comment: I just changed it to `2` then added a second debug `echo` after the `fgets()` and it doesn't echo out, the result is the first `echo` then execution time exceeded error.

Comment: how do you know that the client is sending anything?  What is happening on the client side? Can you provide debug output from the client side?

Comment: I just checked the access logs and I see that the client is returning a reply much longer than the expected `Test complete.` which is 14 bytes in length, the size in the log is 169, so the client is apparently saying something else but I can't really see what..

Comment: Wait, I got a little confused. In this scenario the client is the `Request` object, and the server is my server that I'm in fact sending the request from, so the request and the server are both the server, physically, just different apache threads.

Comment: I suspect that you have an problem with your design in which you are not using the HTTP protocol properly resulting in a mismatch in behavior between client and server. The result of this mismatch is that you are using `fgets()` to read data which the client is not sending and the client is waiting on a response that the server is not sending. The result is that both ends of the connection are waiting for input?

Comment: Well all of the client part is in the question, and all the server is doing is getting the `/test.php` file which consists of exactly two lines `echo 'Test complete.';
exit;` How would that be misconfigured?

Comment: So is the server sending the data out the socket?  What kind of debug information do you have on the server side?

Comment: I just echo out a string. In fact I just tried sending requests out to `stackoverflow.com` and `google.com` and none of these work either, so I guess it's not a server fault :?

Comment: Alright, I made a new discovery. If I remove all headers and leave just `Host` it works. If I add `Cookie` and `Content-Length` headers it doesn't. Don't know what to think anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to test your code, but you are using some sort of Cookie class? I commented that stuff out of the constructor ran the code and everything seems to go.

I get back:

```
Request Object
(
[hostname:protected] => test
[port:protected] => 80
[method:protected] => GET
[uri:protected] => /test.php
[headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [Host] => test
        [Content-Length] => 0
    )

[body:protected] => 
[handle:protected] => Resource id #3
[response:protected] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Feb 2015 13:51:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.4.37
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.37
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: text/html

Hello World
)
```

However, I would highly urge you to do the same as others have suggested, and just use cURL or at the very least a simple file_get_contents() call. Here is a simple cURL function that I use repeatedly and never had an issue.

```
function getUrl( $u ){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $u );


    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data?
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the function. However I'm currently not building anything commercial, just trying to learn this and that and failing miserably. But that's a natural process I guess. I just made a discovery that the client is saying something else than what I expect, refer RichardChambers' answer comments.